# How to set the this manually in a function in javascript?

Tags: javascript

If I have a function like this:

```
function foo(A) {
    console.log(A, this);
}

var e = "world";
```

how can I call `foo`, such that it passes the variable `e` into foo as the `this` variable, and the string `"hello"` for the parameter `A`, so it logs this

```
hello world
```

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like you want to [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) your function.

Comment: isn't it `foo.call(e,"hello")`?

Comment: @omega You got it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Function#call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) *The `call()` method calls a function with a given this value and arguments provided individually.*

In `Function.call`, first argument is always `this-context` and second(and so on) argument will be first argument for called function. That is the reason `"Hello"` is coming first as you have `console.log(A, this);`.

> fun.call(thisArg[, arg1[, arg2[, ...]]])

```js
function foo(A) {
  console.log(A, this);
}

var e = "world";
foo.call(e, 'Hello');
```

**Note:** Important thing to consider, *The value of this provided for the call to `fun`. Note that this may not be the actual value seen by the method: if the method is a function in `non-strict mode` code, `null` and `undefined` will be replaced with the global object and **primitive values will be converted to objects**.*

Comment: @MikeC — Got it.. Thank you :)

Comment: I am not getting how hello is showing up first.  Could you perhaps give a more elementary example please?

Answer (score 0):

```
foo.call(e, "hello ")
```

Use `.call`. The first argument sets `this` and the rest are passed along to the function.

Comment: I don't think you need the space after `hello`. console.log should add that, if you put in more than 1 parameters.